# JavaScript - How to randomly sample items without replacement?

Tags: javascript, probability, random

**JavaScript**

I've tried searching for something like this, but I am not able to find it.

It's a simple idea:

a. Take a random number between 0 to 10.

b. Let's say the random number rolled is a 3.

c. Then, save the number (the 3).

d. Now, take another random number again between 0 to 10, but it can't be the 3, because it has already appeared.

Comment: And what is the question?  Have you tried to write a program and if so, where did you get stuck?  Because the general idea of the program is already there (your list of subtasks sounds OK), and should work.

Comment: Your problem isn't well-defined. Does the probability of the first item and the second item being chosen both have to be equal, or are they intentionally different?

Comment: yes, of course i've tried, there are many codes in internet about generating random number with JS. but i don't know how to make the c) and d)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One solution is to generate an array (a "bucket") with all the values you want to pick, in this case all numbers from 0 to 10. Then you pick one randomly from the array and remove it from the bucket. Note that the example below doesn't check if the bucket is empty, so if you call the function below more than 10 times you will get an error.

```
var bucket = [];

for (var i=0;i<=10;i++) {
    bucket.push(i);
}

function getRandomFromBucket() {
   var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*bucket.length);
   return bucket.splice(randomIndex, 1)[0];
}

// will pick a random number between 0 and 10, and can be called 10 times
console.log(getRandomFromBucket());
```

Comment: The most optimal and elegant solution!

Comment: @skovalyov Maybe the most elegant, but not the most optimal - the last time I tested, `splice` was about half as fast as manually shuffling the elements with a `for` loop. If you don't need to keep the array in order then the fastest way is to move the last element to the random position.

Comment: @Neil response is the most optimal. And simplicity is elegance for the master

Comment: @ShawnCicoria-MSFT I'm not complaining about the elegance, but you use profiling to determine the most optimal solution, not simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

using [d3](https://github.com/d3/d3-array):

```
var bucket = d3.shuffle(d3.range(11));

while(bucket.length) {
  console.log(bucket.pop());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Var rnd = getRnd();

While(rnd != lastRnd)
  rnd = getRnd();
```

Where `getRnd()` is a function that generates your random number.

Actually, you would have to check if your current random number were in an array... And if your list of possible random numbers is small beware of an infinite loop.

Comment: Theoretically, if you're really unlucky, this could loop for quite a while.

Comment: I guess you meant `==`. And a `Var lastRnd = getRnd();` at the start.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
/**
* range Get an array of numbers within a range
* @param min {number} Lowest number in array
* @param max {number} Highest number in array
* @param rand {bool} Shuffle array
* @return {array}
*/
range: function( min, max, rand ) {
  var arr = ( new Array( ++max - min ) )
    .join('.').split('.')
    .map(function( v,i ){ return min + i })
  return rand
    ? arr.map(function( v ) { return [ Math.random(), v ] })
       .sort().map(function( v ) { return v[ 1 ] })
    : arr
}
```

And use it like so:

```
var arr = range( 1, 10, true )
```

Now you have an array with 10 numbers from 1 to 10 in random order and never repeated. So next you can do this:

```
arr.forEach(function( num, i ) { 
  // do something, it will loop 10 times 
  // and num will always be a different number
  // from 1 to 10
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun: derived from @[Strilles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1535827/strille) answer a 'bucket constructor'

```
function RandomBucket(from,until){
  min = (Number(from) || 0);
  max = (Number(until) || 10)+1;
  this.bucket = String(Array(max-min)).split(',').map(function(i){
     return min++;
  });

  if (!RandomBucket.prototype.get){
   RandomBucket.prototype.get = function(){
      var randomValue = 
        this.bucket.length < 2
        ? this.bucket.shift()
        : this.bucket.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*this.bucket.length),1);
       return randomValue || 'bucket empty';
      };
  }
}
```

See [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/h3fD8/) for usage example

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time I'd stick with the method suggested by the other answers - i.e. create an array of possibilities, create a shuffled version of it, then take the first n values as your sample (all operations that are simple and general and can be implemented immutably).

However this isn't great if the range of possibilities is large compared to how much memory you want to use, or compared to how many random values you want to draw (although @Strilles solution uses the memory, but doesn't draw many random values, so is probably the best even for my usecase below).

A solution along the lines your question seems to suggest could look like this:

```js
// select n integers from the range [from, to] (inclusive at both sides),
// don't use this approach for large values of n
// taking random values from the randomSource as needed
function randomNumbersWithoutReplacement(n, from, to, randomSource = Math.random) {
    const result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        // i values have already been taken
        // the +1 makes it inclusive
        const rangeWidth = to - from - i + 1

        let value = Math.floor(rangeWidth * randomSource()) + from

        // correct the value compared to the already sampled integers
        for (let j = 0; j < result.length; ++j) {
            if (result[j] <= value) {
                value++
            }
        }

        result.push(value)

        // sorting makes the correction loop simpler
        // (and it's nice to report the result sorted too)
        result.sort((a, b) => a - b)
    }
    return result
}
```

And why might you want this?

```js
const quantumLottoNumbers = randomNumbersWithoutReplacement(6, 1, 59, quantumRandomSource)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the following **function**, which will draw a sample between 2 numbers based on sample size, and do so without replacement:

```
function random_sample_without_replacement(options) {
    const arr = [];
    while(arr.length < options.sample_size){
        var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * options.population_size) + 1;
        if(arr.indexOf(r) === -1) {
            arr.push(r);
        }
    }
    return(arr)
}
```

**Usage**:

```
random_sample = random_sample_without_replacement({
    population_size : 1000,
    sample_size : 100
})

[950, 725, 239, 273, 814, 325, 834, 702, 209, 740, 539, 281, 799, 459, 443, 758, 567, 124, 428, 462, 576, 234, 35, 344, 441, 580, 461, 371, 354, 616, 704, 233, 486, 296, 182, 63, 57, 357, 226, 969, 396, 879, 904, 718, 22, 121, 835, 52, 310, 359, 593, 793, 421, 870, 719, 959, 639, 755, 85, 10, 365, 189, 457, 895, 168, 574, 115, 176, 252, 284, 840, 721, 962, 780, 851, 71, 144, 827, 843, 643, 54, 246, 838, 100, 452, 303, 20, 572, 259, 102, 909, 471, 642, 8, 716, 388, 374, 338, 425, 880]
```

**check to see if truly without replacement:**

```
[...new Set(random_sample)].length

100
```

Answer (score 0):

As a great person (Joma) once said, "Hashmap, I'll use a Hashmap!".
You can simply store the already taken values as object keys, and check every time you take a new one. If it's present you increase it in a loop until it becomes a not taken value. If it reaches the length, set it to zero.

```
function sample(options, count) {
  if (options < count) {
    throw new Error(
      `Random sample error: can't sample ${count} items without repetition from ${options} options`
    );
  }

  const result = [];
  const exclude = {};

  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * options);
    while (exclude[index]) {
      index += 1;
      index %= options;
    }
    exclude[index] = true;
    result.push(index);
  }
  return result;
}

sample(10, 10);
// [8, 4, 6, 5, 7, 9, 0, 1, 3, 2]
sample(10, 3);
// [1, 6, 7]
```

The computational cost of checking the next index isn't that big cause it uses an object instead of an array.
I don't know if you can determine the needed result size with antecedence, but if not, you can separate the inner `for` code and the `exclude` variable. Or even generate the entire sequence and just `.pop()` new values.

Answer (score 0):

For a large space with picking just two numbers I think you can achieve this without a large array and still uniform probability (and fixed time - no while loop) by picking a number and an offset, something like:

```
const range = 1000000000;
const firstPick = Math.trunc(Math.random()*range);
// range -1 so the offset won't wrap
const offset= Math.trunc(Math.random()*(range-1));
const secondPick = (firstPick+offset)%range;
```

And for more than this I think you could accumulate the picks in sorted order and then adjust the subsequent picks by how many numbers were skipped past (if memory efficiency and runtime efficiency mattered) - though it would get more complex.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that for `k / n < 0.02` (more or less) the `indexOf` approach of @Cybernetic is much quicker. So an efficient implementation would be:

```
const sampleWithoutReplacementLargeK = (arr, k) => {
  arr = arr.slice();
  const n = arr.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
    const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (n - i)) + i;
    const t = arr[index];
    arr[i] = arr[index];
    arr[index] = t;
  }
  return arr.slice(0, k);
}
const sampleWithoutReplacementSmallK = (arr, k) => {
  const idxs = [];
  const n = arr.length;
  while (idxs.length < k) {
    const r = Math.floor(Math.random() * n);
    if (idxs.indexOf(r) === -1) {
      idxs.push(r);
    }
  }
  return idxs.map(i => arr[i]);
}
const sampleWithoutReplacement = (arr, k) => {
  if (k / arr.length < 0.02) { 
    return sampleWithoutReplacementSmallK(arr, k); 
  }
  return sampleWithoutReplacementLargeK(arr, k);
}
```

I'll be happy to see comments and fixes to the above.

Try the [performance test](https://jsperf.app/nobowa/3).