# Want to produce random numbers between 1-45 without repetition

Tags: javascript, titanium

I have come across a very strange problem. I have tried to find its solution but in vain. My problem is that I want to create a random  number between 1-45 and I don't want that number to repeat again.

Comment: Take an. Array, fill it with the range of numbers, shuffle it, pop the values off

Comment: -1. No effort. Random sampling without replacement is not at all a strange problem, it is often encountered in textbooks on programming and there are solutions online in many languages including js. If you had googled "javascript random without replacement" the first three results are from stackoverflow, the first one is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12987719/javascript-how-to-randomly-sample-items-without-replacement .  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11935175/sampling-a-random-subset-from-an-array .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Random selection, by definition, will repeat randomly.

However, you can build an array containing each of your numbers and then shuffle the array, producing a random order of numbers without repetition.

```
var nums = [], i;
for( i=1; i<=45; i++) nums.push(i);
nums.sort(function(a,b) {return Math.random()-0.5;});
alert(nums.join(","));
```

Comment: Be wary of [randomizing arrays that way though...](http://www.robweir.com/blog/2010/02/microsoft-random-browser-ballot.html)

Comment: @maerics interesting article

Answer (score 0):

This is Working code..

```
Random rd =new Random();    
int n = rd.Next(1,45);
```

Comment: >> new Random() ---- "'Random' is undefined"

Comment: This must be JScript/.NET, not pure JavaScript.

Comment: oh yes, my bad, javas random class has a `nextInt` method , mistook it for that

Answer (score 0):

What you really want is to create a set of numbers in a given range and to randomly remove one of the numbers until the set is empty.

Here is a function which generates another function which does exactly that:

```javascript
function generateRandomRangeSet(beg, end) {
  var numbers = []; // Create an array in range [beg, end].
  for (var i=beg; i<=end; i++) { numbers.push(i); }
  return function() {
    if (numbers.length < 1) { throw new Error('no more numbers'); }
    var i=Math.floor(Math.random()*numbers.length), number=numbers[i];
    numbers.splice(i, 1); // Return and remove a random element of the array.
    return number;
  }
}

var r = generateRandomRangeSet(1, 45);
r(); // => 9
r(); // => 24
r(); // => 7 ... for each number [1, 45] then ...
r(); // Error: no more numbers
```

Comment: Relies on new methods of Object.prototype. The above code fails in IE8 and below.

Answer (score 0):

This is working

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
```