# Javascript: generating and storing random draws without replacement

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, replace, qualtrics

I am trying to use Javascript to create an array, take two **unique** random draws from the array, then assign the drawn values to an HTML table. My approach has been to create an array, take a random, create a new array without the drawn value, then take a random draw from the new array as a way of taking two random draws without replacement.

I have provided a minimal example of what I've done to accomplish this, but it's not working. I would like the values assigned to the HTML table to ultimately be two unique values (e.g. "a", "b") from the foo array.
Is this not working because value == bar_a below won't remove the value assigned to the bar_a array because bar_a is an array and not the *value* of the array?

While [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12987719/javascript-how-to-randomly-sample-items-without-replacement) has addressed drawing without replacement, it doesn't provide an example when using strings or explain how to save both numbers and it's unclear why they're using `splice()` rather than `filter()`

```
    // Define array containing the set of values we'll randomly assign to A or B
    var foo = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

    // Initialize variables to hold the value for A and B
    var bar_a=  [""];
    var bar_b=  [""];

    // Randomly draw from foo, save for A
    bar_a =foo[Math.floor(Math.random()*foo.length)];

    // Remove the drawn value from the array, create new array
    var foo_filtered = array.filter(function(value, index, arr){
        return value == bar_a;
        });

    // Randomly draw from foo_filtered, save for B
    bar_b = foo_filtered[Math.floor(Math.random()*foo_filtered.length)];

    // Assign attributes and values to their placeholders (a1, b1) in a HTML table
     document.getElementById("a1").innerHTML = bar_a;
     document.getElementById("b1").innerHTML = bar_b;
```

Comment: The linked answer is using `splice` because it changes the original array, which is exactly what you want, since you don't want a replacement. Have a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lrfhagyu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filter condition logic is backwards. You want values that *don't* equal `bar_a`.

You also need to change `array.filter` to `foo.filter`

```js
    // Define array containing the set of values we'll randomly assign to A or B
    var foo = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

    // Initialize variables to hold the value for A and B
    var bar_a=  [""];
    var bar_b=  [""];

    // Randomly draw from foo, save for A
    bar_a =foo[Math.floor(Math.random()*foo.length)];

    // Remove the drawn value from the array, create new array
    var foo_filtered = foo.filter(function(value, index, arr){
        return value !== bar_a;
                  // ^^ not equal
        });

    // Randomly draw from foo_filtered, save for B
    bar_b = foo_filtered[Math.floor(Math.random()*foo_filtered.length)];

    // Assign attributes and values to their placeholders (a1, b1) in a HTML table
     document.getElementById("a1").innerHTML = bar_a;
     document.getElementById("b1").innerHTML = bar_b;
```

```html
A: <span id="a1"></span>   B: <span id="b1"></span>
```

Comment: Nice catch on the array.filter. This work and I'm accepting the answer, but is there a tradeoff to doing this versus using splice?  What would this look like using splice? New to Javascript and learning on the job by scrapping things together.

Comment: Depends if you need to do it all again or not and would need the original array intact. Numerous ways this could be simplified but I only focused on making what you had work