# Load random images from folder but without repeat using javascript math.floor( math.random) function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to javascript and webdev in general.  Im also new here on stackoverflow. Its great!

I have found a snippet of javascript code that is working well for what I'm trying to achieve.  The script shows random images from a folder but i need it to not repeat the images.

This is the script.

```
var random_images_array = ["smile.gif", "frown.gif", "grim.gif", "bomb.gif"];

function getRandomImage(imgAr, path) {
    path = path || "images/";
    // default path here
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgAr.length);
    var img = imgAr[num];
    var imgStr = '<img src="' + path + img + '" alt = "">';
    document.write(imgStr);
    document.close();
}
```

I just can't figure out how to make it not repeat the images. I have read some solutions online but i guess im not there yet to fully grasp and recreate a working solution.

Comment: Could you share which solutions you read about? Just the link would be enough

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12987719/javascript-how-to-randomly-sample-items-without-replacement/12987776#12987776

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript - How to randomly sample items without replacement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12987719/javascript-how-to-randomly-sample-items-without-replacement)

Comment: I think the way to go about this that you push generated numbers in an array containing the seen numbers and every time check if the new generated number is in that array. If not then create a new random number till you get the desired number.

Comment: Looks like you do not want a random picker, but a randomizer/shuffle for the array and then take the shuffled images in sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the image from the array once you picked it

```
var random_images_array = ["smile.gif", "frown.gif", "grim.gif", "bomb.gif"];

function getRandomImage(path) {
    path = path || "images/";
    // default path here
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * random_images_array.length);
    var img = random_images_array[num];
    var imgStr = '<img src="' + path + img + '" alt = "">';

    /* remove  1 item from index <num> */
    random_images_array.splice(num, 1);

    document.body.innerHTML += imgStr;
    
}
```

or shuffle the array and every time you call the function you only retrieve an element using `pop()` until the array is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Everytime you output image it gets added to a `usedImages` array, and then before new image outputed - check if already been used by comparing with the new array (`usedImages`)

```
var random_images_array = [
    "smile.gif",
    "frown.gif",
    "grim.gif",
    "bomb.gif",
  ];
  let usedImages = [];
  function getRandomImage(imgAr, path) {
    path = path || "images/";
    // default path here
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgAr.length);
    var img = imgAr[num];
    var imgStr = '<img src="' + path + img + '" alt = "">';
    document.write(imgStr);
    if (usedImages.includes(imgStr)) {
      console.log("in there");
    } else {
      usedImages.push(imgStr);
      console.log(`Used Images: ${usedImages}`);
    }
    document.close();
  }
```